# Ask user to enter his/her name, and then reverse the given name and show it on screen. using character array

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is this But i am getting garbage values. how do i make it general so that anyone can use it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
char ch[31];
cin.get(ch,31);
for (int i = 30; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      cout << ch[i];
    }
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply `std::string ch; getline(cin, ch); std::reverse(ch.begin(), ch.end());`?  Also, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking garbage char from you empty cells.

You must first know the number of char inserted by the user

Comment: is there any other way other than this??

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of char arrays, and `std::reverse` instead of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

use `reverse` function from `algorithm` header file and use `string` instead of `char`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string s;
getline(cin,s);
reverse(s.begin(),s.end());

cout<<s<<endl;

return 0;
}
```